# RabbitMQ Web interface shows incorrect data

Tags: rabbitmq

We noticed that the webinterface (management plugin) doesn't show the correct amount of consumers in the details sections. The consumer section list the right amout, but don't show the correct hostnames/channels. E.g:
Consumers: 0
But it shows 6 consumers.

```
sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues -p vhost name consumers
sudo rabbitmqctl list_consumers -p vhost
```

Those commands shows the right consumers. We tried disabling the management pluging, flashing the stats databases, nothing helped. We are using version 3.6.9.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you think this is a bug in RabbitMQ? If so can you reproduce it? If so maybe report it?

Comment: I think so; we will upgrade to 3.6.12 when it's out. There is a chance it contains a fix for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to 3.6.12 solved the issue; we see the right stats again and are able to delete/recreate queues which didn't exist anymore